# Flutter: Why code execution isn't paused using await on Future

Tags: flutter, dart

Call this method:

```
void method() {
  List<String> items = ["A", "B", "C"];
  print("Start of loop");
  items.forEach((String value) async {
    print("Value = $value");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1), () => print("$value")); // why execution isn't paused here
  });
  print("End of loop");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Start of loop
Value = A
Value = B
Value = C
End of loop
A
B
C
```

**Expected output:**

```
Start of loop
Value = A
A
Value = B
B
Value = C
C
End of loop
```

---

**NOTE:**

I know this can be achieved using `for` loop but I want to know why the execution didn't stop using `await` in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `List.forEach` does not respect / await async functions.

When you look at the Implementation section in the docs of [`List.forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) you see that the for loop does not wait for the function that is executed and therefor does not respect any async functions but simply executes them without waiting for their Future to resolve.

You can achieve your intended behavior with [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Future/forEach.html):

```
void method() async {
   List<String> items = ["A", "B", "C"];
   print("Start of loop");
   await Future.forEach(items, (String value) async {
       print("Value = $value");
       await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1), () => print("$value"));
   });
   print("End of loop");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me from where did you find `List.forEach does not respect / await async functions`?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the equivalent to using an `async` function with `forEach` is the following:

```
void method() {
  List<String> items = ["A", "B", "C"];
  print("Start of loop");
  for (String item in items) {
    myAsyncFunction(item);
  }
  print("End of loop");
}

myAsyncFunction(String item) async {
  print("Value = $item");
  await someFuture;
}
```

As you can see, `myAsyncFunction` is still `async` and uses `await`, but there is no pausing within `method()`. With this alternative code, you have the option of making `method()` async and awaiting `myAsyncFunction`, or as someone else suggested, you can use `Future.forEach` instead.

Comment: Thank you, wish I could accept 2 answers. it was very helpful!